# How to solve the problem of french special characters with Angular on internet explorer?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, autocomplete, special-characters, primeng

I working with angular 7 and I use plugin "PrimeNG" for input autocomplete.
On firefox and chrome is work perfectly but on IE 11, I have a problème with special character.
When, I try to type this "Bé" IE sended like this "BÃ©".

Answer (score 0):

Have you get the correct character set specified by a META tag in the HTML page like the below?

```
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If still not working after setting the right character set, you could refer to the resolutions in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928847/internet-explorer-uses-the-wrong-character-set-when-it-renders-an-html). You could try to use one of the following methods:

> - Disable the **Auto-Select** setting in Internet Explorer.
> - Provide the character set in the HTTP headers.
> - Move the META tag to within the first kilobyte of data that is parsed by MSHTML. Although we do not know how much data the parser reads at a time, this location will resolve the issue.
> - Increase the size of the server's initial HTTP response. The initial size should be at least 1 KB.
> - Make sure that the **System Locale** setting matches the character set of the META tag that is specified in the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

THe best solution, I found is to use URl encoding:
[URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)